# By using PHP preg_match, how to get specific substring from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to get substring:

```
myPhotoName
```

from the below string:

```
path/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg
```

using `PHP` `preg_match` function.

Please may somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your criteria and what did you try?

Comment: you can use `preg_match('/myPhotoName/', $str);` but I think this is not the case. I don't know what are you trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Where are you stuck? Please show some effort by yourself. See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preg_match from / to _.

```
$str = "blur/blur/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg";
Preg_match("/.*\/(.*?)_.*(\..*)/", $str, $match);

Echo $match[1] . $match[2];
```

I use `.*?` to match anything between the slash and underscore lazy to make sure it doesn't match all the way to the last underscore.
Edited to make greedy match anything before the /

https://3v4l.org/9oTuj

Performance of regex:
[image]

---

Since it's such a simple pattern you can also use normal substr with strrpos.
Edited to use strrpos to get the last /

```
$str = "blur/blur/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg";
$pos = strrpos($str, "/")+1; // position of /
$str = substr($str, $pos, strpos($str, "_")-$pos) . substr($str, strpos($str, "."));
// ^^ substring from pos to underscore and add extension

Echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/d411c

Performnce of substring:
[image]

> **My conclusion**
>   Regex is not suitable for this type of job as it's way to slow for such a simple substring pattern.

Comment: Will return incorrect result if the "photo name" contains an underscore.

Comment: But that is not what OP has said. If you want a flamewar then have a look at your own "pattern" it's extremely fixed. Any extra letter or char and it will fail.

Comment: lol I don't want a "flamewar". Chill. I'm just pointing it out. Though OP left no requirements so it's anyone's guess...

Comment: Then why point it out? It's quite obvious but you can say it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for this condition: "blur/blur/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg", it outputs "blur/myPhotoName". The format after "myPhotoName" is constant. It needs to get the string after "/" and before "_20170818_111453.jpg". The extension may be anyting ".jpg" or ".jpeg" or ".pdf". :D

Comment: u are right for regex, which is not suitable for this type of simple problem.

Comment: Thank you brother. It works. :D But now I need to add extension to it. Could you help me? :)

Comment: ? extension? You mean `photoname` + `jpg` or whatever the extension was?

Comment: Yes. whatever the extension is. :)

Comment: I mean photoname + any extension

Comment: Yes? And that is what it does.

Comment: @KyawZinHtet See here: https://3v4l.org/4E8Ip#output and https://3v4l.org/dasg2 they both work with any extension

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
<?php
$arr = "path/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg";
$res = explode('_',explode('/',$arr)[1])[0];
print_r($res);
?>
```

Use explode function in place of preg_match for easily get your expected output.
And using preg_match, do like this:

```
<?php
$img = "path/myPhotoName_20170818_111453.jpg";
preg_match("/path\/(.+)\_[0-9]*\_[0-9]*\.jpg/", $img, $folder);
print_r($folder[1]);
?>
```

Comment: try it for your expected output

Comment: It works brother. :) Thank you for the edit suggestion too.